# Terragrunt dependencies for aws_ssm_parameter

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt, aws-parameter-store

I tried to figure out a good way to use AWS Parameter Store in my Terragrunt config.

I created module `secrets` to create all my secret parameters:

```
# secrets/main.tf

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "postgres_password" {
  name        = "${var.env}-postgres-password"
  description = "The parameter description"
  type        = "SecureString"
  value       = var.postgres_password
  tags =  var.tags
}
```

With outputs:

```
# secrets/outputs.tf

output "postgres_password" {
  description = "Postgres password"
  value       = try(aws_ssm_parameter.postgres_password.name, "")
}
```

I then created the dependency for this module:

```
# dependency-blocks/secrets.hcl

dependency "secrets" {
  config_path = "${get_original_terragrunt_dir()}/../../data-stores/secrets"
  mock_outputs = {
    postgres_password= "staging-postgres-password"
  }
  mock_outputs_allowed_terraform_commands = ["validate", "plan", "init"]
}
```

In my database config, I included the secrets dependency and set it as input for my Database module:

```
# db/terragrunt.hcl

include "secrets" {
  path = "../../../../dependency-blocks/secrets.hcl"
  expose = true
  merge_strategy = "deep"
}


inputs = {
  postgres_password = dependency.secrets.outputs.postgres_password
}
```

Than I tried to refer to this parameter in db module:

```
# db/main.tf

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "password" {
  name = var.postgres_password 
}
```

When I run `terragrunt run-all plan` it ends with error:

```
Error describing SSM parameter (staging-postgres-password): ParameterNotFound: Parameter staging-postgres-password not found.
```

and I know that's because I mocked only the name, but I don't have `ssm parameter resource` created yet.

My questions:

1. how to make this `plan` command work?
2. It also led me to the question that maybe creating a module for parameters is not a good idea and I should manage them outside Terraform config?

Could you recommend some of your good practices to work with parameters in Terragrunt/Terraform?